# playframework and wiring in sourcecode generation

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

playframework 1.2.4

How to wire in source code generation from an xsd or from google's protobuf so that the generated source code

1. Is NOT in the app directory as we do NOT want that in version control
2. Is in the source path of play AND in eclipse after running eclipsify

Is this even possible?  (I kinda wished they used gradle and am so sad they went with sbt as sbt was just so weird with very odd rules like needing two line spaces between lines back when we used it).

later,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that trying to place source files somewhere else than under app directory would break one of the basic paradigm of playframework and therefore I believe that it is not even possible (not sure of that).

However I have two propositions:

1. If your only intent is not having the generated source code in version control, you can still place it under app directory, but set your version control system to ignore such files (all major version control systems support ignore lists)
2. If you do not want this code to be under main app directory, then consider moving that code into separate playframework module. This would bring some separation and you can then decide what parts of the module will be in version control.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bwajtr,

You can store your project source code where you want and turn your /app into a symbolic link (`ln -s`).

You can version your symbolic link in you VCS.

***Update :***

You can have a look at Play documentation for sbt sub project [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SBTSubProjects)